# Sumar dato a fecha en tiempo real

Tags: javascript, html

Necesito que cuando se le agregue un dato a un `input`, este al momento le sume el día a una fecha. Tengo el siguiente código, el cual hace la acción de sumar el día, pero en este caso es en un `<button>`.

```js
function calcular() {
    
    var numero = document.getElementById('numero');

    var Fecha = new Date();
    y = Fecha.getFullYear();
    m = Fecha.getMonth() + 1;
    d = Fecha.getDate();
    var dias = parseInt(numero.value);
    Fecha.setDate(Fecha.getDate() + dias);
    resultado.innerText = Fecha.getDate() + '/' +
            (Fecha.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + Fecha.getFullYear();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="numero"/>
  <button onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button>
</p>
<p>Resultado: <span id="resultado"></span></p>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es simplemente ejecutar la función por medio del evento `change` aplicado al `input`, este evento lo que hace es identificar el cambio de valor y ejecutar la función.

```js
function calcular() {
    var numero = document.getElementById('numero');

    var Fecha = new Date();
    y = Fecha.getFullYear();
    m = Fecha.getMonth() + 1;
    d = Fecha.getDate();
    var dias = numero.value == '' ? 0 : parseInt(numero.value);
    
    Fecha.setDate(Fecha.getDate() + dias);
    resultado.innerText = Fecha.getDate() + '/' +
            (Fecha.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + Fecha.getFullYear();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="numero"/ onchange="calcular()">

<p>Resultado: <span id="resultado"></span></p>
```

También podrías usar otros eventos como `keyup` o `keydown` dependiendo el resultado exacto que desees.

```js
function calcular() {
    var numero = document.getElementById('numero');

    var Fecha = new Date();
    y = Fecha.getFullYear();
    m = Fecha.getMonth() + 1;
    d = Fecha.getDate();
    var dias = numero.value == '' ? 0 : parseInt(numero.value);
   
    Fecha.setDate(Fecha.getDate() + dias);
    resultado.innerText = Fecha.getDate() + '/' +
            (Fecha.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + Fecha.getFullYear();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="numero"/ onkeyup="calcular()">

<p>Resultado: <span id="resultado"></span></p>
```

Adicional a todo esto agregué una validación a tu variable `dias` para evitar que te salga `NAN` en el resultado.

Comment: Gracias, en base a tu respuesta, logre solucionarlo, pero me toco que tambien añadir un .onkeyup .

Comment: @Lux686ЮЮЯ genial, también te hice un ejemplo con el onkeyup y te agregué una pequeña validación, te invito a finalizar la pregunta marcando la respuesta como aceptada para que sea de ayuda a otros desarrolladores

Comment: No hay problema, Gracias!